# D3 sunburst diagram: Setting arc.cornerRadius() causes invalid path with arcTween

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I try to create a dynamic sunburst chart, which zooms the selected arc and hides the other arcs. This works pretty well, as long as i avoid to use arc.cornerRadius() with a value greater than 0.

I logged the generated arc in the (attrTween) arcTween function and the output seems correct to me, but following svg paths differ, where the second one causes an error in the d3.min.js:5.

Correct path:

```
M0,58.528989440000004A58.528989440000004,58.528989440000004 0 1,1 0,-58.528989440000004A58.528989440000004,58.528989440000004 0 1,1 0,58.528989440000004M0,55A55,55 0 1,0 0,-55A55,55 0 1,0 0,55Z
```

Error path:

```
M0,55.73917966222222A55.73917966222222,55.73917966222222 0 1,1 0,-55.73917966222222A55.73917966222222,55.73917966222222 0 1,1 0,55.73917966222222M0,55A55,55 0 1,0 0,-55A55,55 0 1,0 0,55Z
```

This is how i set the radius:

```
    var graphMaxRadius = 83;
    var innerBtnRadius = 55;
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, xScale(d.x))); })
                .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, xScale(d.x + d.dx))); })
                .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(innerBtnRadius, yScale(d.y)); })
                .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(yScale(d.y + d.dy), graphMaxRadius)); })
                .cornerRadius(function(d) { return 10;});
```

My first guess was, that the cornerRadius conflicts the hiding arcs and the invalid svg happens, so i tried various sizes. But everything > 0 causes the error with an output of:

```
    M0,55A55,55 0 1,1 0,-55A55,55 0 1,1 0,55M0,50.006635519999996A50.006635519999996,50.006635519999996 0 1,0 0,-50.006635519999996A50.006635519999996,50.006635519999996 0 1,0 0,50.006635519999996Z
    d3.min.js:5 Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNANaN,NaN 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNANaN,NaN 0 0,1 NaN,NaNZ"
d3.min.js:5 (anonymous function)
d3.min.js:3 l
d3.min.js:1 Lt
d3.min.js:1 qt
```

This is my arcTween function (EDITED in correspondance to mbostok on [github issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2183)):

```
return function arcTween(d) {
        var xd = d3.interpolate(xScale.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
        var yd = d3.interpolate(yScale.domain(), [d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

        var selectionRadius = innerBtnRadius - 5;
        //radius -5 reduces width of inner circle and selection rim
        var yr = d3.interpolate(yScale.range(), [d.y ? selectionRadius : innerBtnRadius, radius-5]);

        return function(d, i) {
            return i
                ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
                : function(t) { xScale.domain(xd(t)); yScale.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
        };
    }
```

Any ideas please, what can i check next?

p.s. <strike>sry, no jsfiddle because they have currently not the d3 v3.5 installed</strike> (i'm missing a data import). My code ressembles the example here: [zoomable sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)

Here is a screenshot of the breakpoint in the d3.js lib where the error occurs, but i still have no idea:

[image: This is where the error occurs in the d3.js]

Comment: I changed a little bit the title, hopefully for better.

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that cornerRadius is relatively new feature of D3 partition layout, so there may still be some bugs related to it.

However, my impression is that your problem is not there.

Based on the example that you linked to, I created a small [codepen](http://codepen.io/VividD/pen/myRWRY).

It is the same as the example, just it uses smalled data set, and keeps data in the script itself, instead in JSON file.

Also, I integrated cornerRadius, checked for variety of values - and everything works like charm, as seen in the pics below.

I couldn't integrate your tween function, since some bits and peaces are missing from the rest of the code.

*So, it looks you need to **check and rewrite your code**, especially anything related to arcTween().*

Screenshots illustrating valid execution in my example:

`cornerRadius` is 5:

[image]

`cornerRadius` is 20:

[image]

`cornerRadius` is 100:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this impressive answer! I'll give it a try and be back asap.

Comment: I tried your codepen in Safari 7.1 and chrome 39.0 and the same error pops up in the console (>1000 times). Safari's console shows a "Error: Problem parsing d="....."" and chrome has the same with: "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="....."". Do you have this errors too in your console? Which browser did you use?

Comment: Windows laptop, my codeoen: Firefox - no error messages, Chrome - lots of error messages! @StefanWasserbauer

Comment: thanks for investigation! Same on mac, firefox has no errors. I will contact the d3 github project, as it seems that this is a bug of d3.js. Do you mind if i link to your codepen?

Comment: @StefanWasserbauer Go ahead with linking! Hope this problem is now clearer, and will become solved soon.